# Modifying detailNavigationBar but modifies rootNavigationBar too

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, pushviewcontroller

I have a problem when pushViewController from MainViewController to DetailViewController. My navigationBar in MainViewController is white but when i change the navigationBar items in DetailViewController to white or backgrondColor to clear, it changes too in MainViewController. Its like the view is the same but push only the background...

Main View
[image]

Detail View
[image]

Main View Again
[image]

I'm programmatically writing my app (without storyboard). The AppDelegate is this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    /********** Storyboard Config **********/
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window?.rootViewController = TabBarController()
    
    return true
}
```

The TabBarController is this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    
    // Create Tab MainViewController
    let mainNavigationController = MainViewController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    mainNavigationController.title = "Main"
    let mainController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainNavigationController)
    mainController.title = "Main"
    mainController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "UITabBarBookmarksTemplate")
    mainController.tabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "UITabBarBookmarksTemplateSelected")
    
    // Create Tab UserViewController
    let userNavigationController = UserViewController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    userNavigationController.title = ""
    let userController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: userNavigationController)
    userController.title = "Profile"
    userController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "UITabBarContactsTemplate")
    userController.tabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "UITabBarContactsTemplateSelected")
    
    viewControllers = [mainController, userController]
    
}
```

The pushViewController code of MainViewController is:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let controller = DetailViewController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    controller.data = cloudDatas?[indexPath.item]
    
    navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
}
```

And the only thing i change in DetailViewController is this:

```
// Translucent Navigation Bar
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
```

With this code the navigationBar in MainView controller changes from white to clearColor when i navigate to DetailViewController and return to MainView Controller...

What is the problem?? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the below in `DetailViewController`:

```
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
```

In place of this:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
```

And add this in `MainViewController`, `viewWillAppear`:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the buttons it DetailViewController doesn't appear (because the navbar is hidden) and when return to MainView the navbar looks translucent too like the pictures above...